# Jnice checkbox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

i got a little problem whit the jnice plugin.
i found a work arround to make work something like a click method.
its something like this

```
 $("checkbox").parent().find("a").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("jNiceChecked")){
        //action when is checked
    }else{
        //unchecked
    }
   });
```

so it works fine on the chrome console but it doesnt get executed in code even whit the document ready function.
i guess the problem is that jnice.js creates the dom element after the document gets ready so i can select dom elements that dont exist yet.
is there some jnice method or a worck arround for getting the code executed?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind to those DOM elements. Something like this:

```
$("checkbox").parent().find("a").on("click", function() ...
```

Comment: still same result, when i execute the javascript from console it works, but in code its not working. i guess that jnice creates the elements after document is ready...i hate this plugins :P

Comment: in fact when i set a timeout to execute the code it works but i dont like this nasty solution

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to need to bind to an element that exists on the page and then further drill down to the anchor link. Does the `a` have an `id` or something? What about the `checkbox`?